# Electron-positron pair production requiring a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, pair-production

I was told that a nucleus is required to be present to allow the conservation of energy and momentum in the production of an electron and positron from a high energy photon, during pair production.

However, if the nucleus is removed, how can it be shown that the energy and momentum can't be conserved?

What I tried to do is 
$$E_\zeta =h\nu=E_++E_-$$
$$h\nu=m_0c^2+K_++m_0c^2+K_-$$
and 
$$p_\zeta=p_++p_-$$

and using the relationship that 
$$p=\frac{E}{c}$$

to show that these statements are impossible but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: try looking at what happens when you start with a photon that has $E=2m_e c^2$. What should the momentum of the electron and positron be in that case?

Comment: Or look at the center-of-mass frame of the electron-positron pair.

Comment: Note that $p = E/c$ is not a general relationship. Under what circumstances is it exact?

Comment: see my asnwer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353083/energy-not-conserved-in-pair-production/353099#353099

Answer (score 1):

A way to show that a single photon cannot decay into a massive particle-antiparticle pair can be wrote down by using the four-vector formalism. The decay is
$$
k^\alpha=p_1^\alpha+p_2^\alpha
$$
where $k$ is the four-vector of the photon while $p_1$ and $p_2$ are those of the particle and its antiparticle. Taking the square you have
$$
0 = m^2+p_1^\alpha p_{2\alpha} =m^2+E_1E_2-\vec{p_1}\cdot\vec{p_2}
$$
where $E_i$ are the energies and $\vec{p_i}$ the spatial momenta with $i=\{1,2\}$. This is reference-independent, i.e. we didn't choose any particular reference system. Now a crucial observation: due to the symmetry of the system and the conservation of the spatial momentum, the particle and the anti-particle momenta must have the same module. Since the particles have also the same mass $m$, then also their energies must be equal
$$
E_1=E_2=E \qquad |\vec{p_1}|=|\vec{p_2}|=p
$$
and the mass-shell relation holds $E^2-p^2=m^2$. Now, substituting
$$
0 = m^2+E^2-p^2\cos\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the directions of the particle and the anti-particle (notice that the problem lies in just two dimensions, and also that the reference system in which the total momentum is zero corresponds to $\theta=\pi$, i.e. back-to-back particles). Now we just have to find a majorant of the equation above. Since
$$
E^2-p^2\cos\theta \geq E^2-p^2 = m^2 \qquad \theta\in[0,\pi]
$$
then
$$
0 \geq 2m^2
$$
which is wrong.